# FOSUserBundle ProfileFormType -> create different form

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle, overriding

i'm on a Symfony project ( v2.5 ) and i'm using FOSUserBundle & OAuth for the login/sign in.

My problem is : I have different type of user with some that has more informations to edit in /profile/edit. That's why i'm trying in a simple way to get user informations to do a condition in the form builder. With one attribute i'm able to know which type of user i have and which form he needs.

After a lot of research i found this https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md
but that doesn't seem to be the best for my little problem.

Best regards,

Thanks for replying

Comment: We had the same problem (many custom attributes, profile picture etc.) and ended up by implementing our own logic instead of using the FOSUserBundle templates and controller actions for editing profiles...

Comment: I've not that much time to recreate a perfect user bundle :/ 
I'm still trying to change this

Comment: Should i pass this attribute in the $_SESSION? but how ?

Comment: ok so in the builder by $username = explode( '"' ,explode( ';' , explode(':',$_SESSION['_sf2_attributes']['_security_main'])['34'])[0])[1]; i can have the username ( that is in fact the email which is primary ) i'm now trying to have a proper way ( because what i've done is already to nasty ) to find the user attribute ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way ( nasty but working )

Before creating the form, i've access to user, so I set the attribute in the Session, catching the attribute in the builder then unsetting the session